# Too wide column width in Pandas (jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I tried to rename columns and display the dataframe.

Here, I got a problem with some of column titles; a linebreak that I did not intend and the width could not be controlled.

The funny fact is that I got no problem with another dataframe.

Here is the result

**1. test for 5 rows, the first group:**
[image: 1. test for 5 rows, the first group]

**2. test for 5 rows, the second group:**
[image: 2. test for 5 rows, the second group]

Here is the code:

You may find I tried display.width options and so on...

```py
# sample5_type1 = ['power.csv', 'hep-th-1999.csv', 'reactome.csv', 'euroroad.csv', 'DC.csv']
# sample5_type2 = ['Microarray.csv','collins_yeast.csv', 'bible_nouns.csv', 'APS2015.csv', 'L2.csv']
anomallus = summary_df.loc[(summary_df['name'].isin(sample5_type2) )]
# anomallus = summary_df.loc[(summary_df[r'$\rho_{max}$'] < summary_df[r'$\rho_{net}$'])]
columns_titles = [r'name',r'# nodes',r'# edges',r'$\langle k \rangle$'
                      ,r'$k^{\ast}$',r'max $k_s$',r'core_parameter']
# df2 = df.rename({'a': 'X', 'b': 'Y'}, axis='columns')
# pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 20)
# pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
# pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
eg = anomallus.reindex(columns=columns_titles)
reg = eg.rename(columns = {eg.columns[4]: r'$k_{s}^{*}$', eg.columns[5]: r'$k_{s}^{m}$', eg.columns[6]: r'$k_{s}^{*}$/$k_{s}^{m}$'})

# reg.to_csv('ex_type2.csv', index=False)
# reg.style.set_properties(subset=[r'$k_{s}^{*}$/$k_{s}^{m}$'], **{'width': '10px'})
# pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)

display(reg)
```

Comment: Might it not be the title, but one of the values in that column?

Comment: Well, the types of values are quite mixed up as you commented... I'll try to convert them into float. Thanks for your comment.